# Added iterating over page id in Scrapy, responses in parse method no longer run

Tags: python, regex, loops, xpath, scrapy

I have a few print functions in my spider for debugging. In the `start_request` function, I'm generating urls by adding numbers in the range [0,4] with base url which gets parsed by `parse_grant` function.In that function, first print function gets called, but second does not.

Still learning here, so I may have made a stupid mistake and don't quite understand what's happening with Twisted in the background.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spiders import Spider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request

from scraper_app.items import NSERCGrant

from scrapy.selector import Selector

class NSERC_Spider(Spider):

name = 'NSERCSpider'
allowed_domains = ["http://www.nserc-crsng.gc.ca"]
# Maximum page id to use.
max_id = 5

def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(self.max_id):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        yield Request("http://www.nserc-crsng.gc.ca/ase-oro/Details-Detailles_eng.asp?id=%d" % i,
                      callback=self.parse_grant)

def parse_grant(self, response):

    print("Being called")

    sel = Selector(response)
    grants = sel.xpath('.//html//body')
    items = []

    for response in grants:

        print("Responses being called")

        item = NSERCGrant()

        # Row one
        item['Competition_Year'] = response.xpath('.//tr[1]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Fiscal_Year'] = response.xpath('.//tr[1]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row two
        item['Project_Lead_Name'] = response.xpath('.//tr[2]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Institution'] = response.xpath('.//tr[2]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row three
        item['Department'] = response.xpath('.//tr[3]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Province'] = response.xpath('.//tr[3]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row four
        item['Award_Amount'] = response.xpath('.//tr[4]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Installment'] = response.xpath('.//tr[4]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row five
        item['Program'] = response.xpath('.//tr[5]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Selection_Committee'] = response.xpath('.//tr[5]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row six
        item['Research_Subject'] = response.xpath('.//tr[6]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Area_of_Application'] = response.xpath('.//tr[6]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row seven
        item['Co_Researchers'] = response.xpath(".//tr[7]//td[2]//text()").extract()
        item['Partners'] = response.xpath('.//tr[7]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Award Summary
        item['Award_Summary'] = response.xpath('.//p//text()').extract()

        items.append(item)

    return items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you are looking for only occurs once on each page and the body tag is on every page so the loop and the line

```
grants = sel.xpath('.//html//body')
```

are redundant. Also, `response.xpath('... your xpath here ...')` saves some code. Try this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request

from scraper_app.items import NSERCGrant

class NSERC_Spider(Spider):

    name = 'NSERCSpider'
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.nserc-crsng.gc.ca"]
    # Maximum page id to use.
    max_id = 5

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(1, self.max_id):
            yield Request("http://www.nserc-crsng.gc.ca/ase-oro/Details-Detailles_eng.asp?id=%d" % i,
                          callback=self.parse_grant)

    def parse_grant(self, response):

        print("Being called")

        item = NSERCGrant()

        # Row one
        item['Competition_Year'] = response.xpath('//tr[1]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Fiscal_Year'] = response.xpath('//tr[1]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row two
        item['Project_Lead_Name'] = response.xpath('//tr[2]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Institution'] = response.xpath('//tr[2]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row three
        item['Department'] = response.xpath('//tr[3]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Province'] = response.xpath('//tr[3]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row four
        item['Award_Amount'] = response.xpath('//tr[4]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Installment'] = response.xpath('//tr[4]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row five
        item['Program'] = response.xpath('//tr[5]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Selection_Committee'] = response.xpath('//tr[5]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row six
        item['Research_Subject'] = response.xpath('//tr[6]//td[2]//text()').extract()
        item['Area_of_Application'] = response.xpath('//tr[6]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Row seven
        item['Co_Researchers'] = response.xpath("//tr[7]//td[2]//text()").extract()
        item['Partners'] = response.xpath('//tr[7]//td[4]//text()').extract()

        # Award Summary
        item['Award_Summary'] = response.xpath('//p//text()').extract()

        yield item
```

I've also tweaked your start_request routine to remove the `if i = 0`.

Take a look at `scrapy shell` which allows you to try out your xpaths and see the results interactively.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed response Steve. I understand much better now, not just this code - but also some of what I had written in my previous spiders as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I try

```
grants = sel.xpath('.//html//body')
```

from my scrapy shell, this is what I get

```
In [10]: grants = sel.xpath('.//html//body')

In [11]: grants
Out[11]: []
```

When I change it to the following code,

```
In [12]: grants = sel.xpath('/html/body')

In [13]: grants
Out[13]: [<Selector xpath='/html/body' data=u'<body>\r\n<div id="cn-body-inner-1col">\r\n<'>]
```